# Select all users with specific tags from tags settings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this model of table

[image: Model]

I want to select all users WHERE tags (users_tags) are in tags setting (s_users_tag) of a specific user

I don't know how to do that.
I think is with this code

```
WHERE (req) IN (SELECT tags.name FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `s_users_tags` ON tags.id = s_users_tags.tag_id  WHERE users_tags.user_uuid = "uuid of specific user"
```

But I don't know how write the first request or the first mumber (req)

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything called `req` in your data model.

Comment: Yes req is the part of the request I don't know how to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer for my problem

```
SELECT *
           FROM users
           WHERE exists (select * from `tags`
               inner join `users_tags` on `tags`.`id` = `users_tags`.`tag_id`
           where `users`.`uuid` = `users_tags`.`user_uuid` and tags.`id` in (1,2,4))
```

Where (1,2,4) come for an other request

Answer (score 0):

Well as everyone go for his little solution i try too :|

```
WITH USER_TAGGED AS (SELECT s_user_tags.user_uuid FROM user
JOIN users_tags ON users_tags.iuser_uuid = user.uuid
JOIN s_user_tags ON s_user_tags.tag_id = users_tags.tag_id
WHERE user.uuid = "uuid of specifi user")
SELECT * FROM user
JOIN USER_TAGGED ON user.uuid = USER_TAGGED.user_uuid
```

But i think we all better understand with sample of data from every table.
Can you tell us what is exactly s_user_tags please

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking so I will answer the question I *think* you are asking:

**I want to find all users who have at least one tag that is both a users_tag and a s_users_tag.**

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN users_tags ON users_tags.user_uuid = users.uuid 
INNER JOIN s_users_tags on s_users_tags.user_uuid = users.uuid
WHERE users_tags.tag_id=s_users_tags.tag_id
```